# unrecognized create collection options field: timeseries

Tags: mongodb, time-series, datagrip

I am trying to use DataGrip to create a timeseries collection on MongoDB, but it returned: **unrecognized create collection options field: timeseries**. How may I fix it?

```js
db.createCollection
(
    "data_point_timeseries",
    {
        timeseries:
        {
             timeField: "timestamp",
             metaField: "metadata",
             granularity: "seconds"
        }
    }
)

[2022-04-07 10:20:44] unrecognized create collection options field: timeseries
```

- DataGrip version: 2021.3.4
- DataGrip MongoDB driver version: 1.14
- MongoDB version: 5.0.3
- MongoDB feature compatibility version: 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll fix it in the next driver update.
You can follow the issue in JetBrains bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14915